# Real-time HTTP stream writing console

Tags: windows, http, testing

Is there a program available that will allow me to interactively write HTTP stream data and send it to a server? Ideally I'm looking for a console app that will allow me to type or paste HTTP headers and body, send it to my server, and get the response headers and body back.

Does such a program already exist?

I'm running W7 64-bit with .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you change your mind and want a GUI app

http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/

or you can also use fiddler

Edit:

http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/ also supports commandline

Comment: Just give the rest-client a try and it's pretty handy!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `telnet` is an option for you? If it's not already installed on your machine, take a look at [this guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Telnet-frequently-asked-questions) from MS.

To connect to your server use it like this:

```
telnet www.myserver.de 80
```

After the connection is established, you can paste your HTTP GET reqests or what ever you like.

Comment: I've done exactly what you describe using telnet in the past. It was the recommended technique in the web programming book I read in 1994.

Answer (score 0):

tinyget is a useful MSFT tool that will make simple get requests.  You can store these requests in text files and stream them in.